# Solving integral depending on $a$

Tags: calculus, integration

So the problem I have is with this integral: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)^a}\,\mathrm dx, a > 0$$ I tried with factoring but didn't get anywhere. Some hint? Could any trick be applied here?

Comment: You do you know about $a$?

Comment: Consider $a\in\mathbb Z^-$, the integral equals $\infty$. It is important to know whether you mean $a\in\mathbb R, a\in\mathbb Z$ or $a\in\mathbb N$. By the way, I don't think that you can solve it by simple facrtorization, as you need more powerful mathematics tools... If you want to use factorization, perhaps the only obvious one is the case $a=1$.

Comment: Just enforce the substitution $x=\frac{\sqrt{3}\tan\theta-1}{2}$.

Comment: You can also use the residue theorem.

Comment: Sorry to answer so late,it says a>0

Comment: For some values of $a$ you allow the integral diverges. A quick check gives $a>\frac{1}{2}$ (according to my CAS). If required I think you need to update your question to help you find this lower real bound on convergence explicitly

Comment: @Botond although I understood the solution given below I'm interested to know about the residue theorem too and I searched it on the net but I don't see how I could apply it here , could you give me some hint?

Comment: @Lola I added it as an answer because it's too long for a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By letting $x=\frac{\sqrt{3}\tan\theta-1}{2}$ we turn the original integral into

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{a}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos(\theta)^{2a-2}\,d\theta =\color{red}{\frac{2\pi\sqrt{3}}{3^a}\binom{2a-2}{a-1}}.$$

Comment: How could I think of this substitution fast? is there any theorem behind it or just a trick,sorry if this sounds stupid but I've seen many of this type of integrals

Comment: $(x^2+x+1)=(x+1/2)^2+3/4=\frac{3}{4} \left(\left[\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}(x+1/2)\right]^2+1\right)$, then you make $\tan \theta= \frac{2}{\sqrt 3}(x+1/2)$

Answer (score 0):

The denominator's roots are at $x_{\pm}=-\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$. For the residue theorem, we want to enclose $1$ pole with a half circle. If we pick $x_+$, the circle will be in the upper half, and it will only enclose the pole at $x_+$. We can rewrite your function as
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)^a}=\frac{(x-x_-)^{-a}}{(x-x_+)^a}$$
And if $a \in \mathbb{N}$, and it's big enough for the integral of semicircle to vanish, the integral will just be the residue of $f$ at $x_+$:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f=2i \pi \text{Res}(f, x_+)$$
And the residue is:
$$\text{Res}(f, x_+)=\frac{1}{(a-1)!}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{a-1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{a-1}}\left((x-x_+)^af(x)\right)_{x=x_+}$$
$$\text{Res}(f, x_+)=\frac{1}{(a-1)!}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{a-1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{a-1}}\left((x-x_-)^{-a}\right)_{x=x_+}$$
Differentiating it $a-1$ times we can get that:
$$\text{Res}(f, x_+)=\frac{1}{(a-1)!}(-a)(-a-1)\dots(-a-(a-1)+2)(x_+-x_-)^{-a-(a-1)}$$
$$\text{Res}(f, x_+)=\frac{1}{(a-1)!}(-1)^{a-1}(a)(a+1)\dots(2a-2)(x_+-x_-)^{-2a+1}$$
And because $x_+-x_-=\sqrt{3}i$:
$$\text{Res}(f, x_+)=\frac{1}{(a-1)!}(-1)^{a-1}(a)(a+1)\dots(2a-2)(\sqrt{3}i)^{-2a+1}$$
$$\text{Res}(f, x_+)=\frac{1}{(a-1)!}(-1)^{a-1}(a)(a+1)\dots(2a-2)\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{(\sqrt{3}i)^{2a}}$$
$$\text{Res}(f, x_+)=\frac{1}{(a-1)!}(-1)^{a-1}(a)(a+1)\dots(2a-2)\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{3^a (i)^{2a}}$$
$$\text{Res}(f, x_+)=\frac{1}{(a-1)!}(-1)^{a-1}(a)(a+1)\dots(2a-2)\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{3^a (-1)^{a}}$$
$$\text{Res}(f, x_+)=-\frac{1}{(a-1)!}(a)(a+1)\dots(2a-2)\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{3^a }$$
So the integral is:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f=2i \pi \text{Res}(f, x_+)$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f=2i \pi \left(-\frac{1}{(a-1)!}(a)(a+1)\dots(2a-2)\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{3^a }\right)$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f=2 \pi \frac{1}{(a-1)!}(a)(a+1)\dots(2a-2)\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3^a}$$
And from a little comparision with [Jack D'Aurizio's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2831473/281471), and with the verification of [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(product%20i,%20i%3Da...2*a-2)-(a-1)!*binom(2a-2,a-1)), we can rewrite the product as:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f=2 \pi \binom{2a-2}{a-1}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3^a}$$